# Rescuing Exception within Ruby Interpolation in a HAML Document

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I have a bit of interpolated ruby code in a HAML document that looks like the following:

```
:javascript
    a = { 'something' : "#{model.attribute.present? ? method(parameter) : ''}" }
```

However, the method(parameter) is throwing exceptions with some parameters, so I would like to rescue the exception. When the exception is thrown, I would like the 'something' key to be mapped to something else.

I am not clear on the exact syntax of how to do this with the HAML code/ruby interpolation. I've tried a couple things, but it's not working.

Thanks!

Comment: can you be more specific? I don't really know what you mean.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should take this line

```
model.attribute.present? ? method(parameter) : ''
```

and make a helper method out of it

```
class ApplicationHelper
  def some_method
    model.attribute.present? ? method(parameter) : ''
  rescue
    "something else" # this is your value in case of exception
  end
end
```

Then your HAML becomes trivial

```
:javascript
    a = { 'something' : "#{some_method}" }
```